# JxBrowser BrowserFactory missing from driver file

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I am trying to install JxBrowser (following [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/google-maps-java-swing)), and after installing the JxBrowser driver:

[image]

I tried to compile, and noticed the necessary import `BrowserFactory` was missing:

[image]

And, rummaging through the class files in the driver, sure enough there's no `BrowserFactory` available:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a necessary component to JxBrowser that I am missing? Does the new version of the driver not include a `BrowserFactory` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sample at https://dzone.com/articles/google-maps-java-swing is based on JxBrowser 4.x API. You use JxBrowser 5.x API which is a little bit different. Now, with 5.x API, to create `Browser` instance you don't need to use `BrowserFactory` class.

The following sample demonstrates how to write same code with JxBrowser 5.x API:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * This sample demonstrates how to load a web page with Google Maps
 * and control it using JxBrowser API.
 */
public class GoogleMapsSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JxBrowser Google Maps");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.loadURL("http://maps.google.com");
    }
}
```